# Why making rainbow background on the body tag doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to make the background color of the body to change dynamicly from a list of colors. Of course, I need it to change **smoothly**. If you have any ideas, please help! Also it has to be in a cycle, so the colors will repeat. I am thinking of `while(1)`

I have tryed looking everywhere!

***P.S.*** I have tryed changing it with `DOM`, but I couldn't succeed.
I have tryed the following **JavaScript**

```
while(1){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Does it makes any sense?
I have just tried everything! If you have any idea, please be sure to share it!

Comment: Never use a while loop to update DOM if you want to see it happen. Instead use a setTimeout or setInterval

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to this actually involves no javascript at all, just plain CSS:

```css
body {
  animation: rainbow 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rainbow {
  0% {background-color: red;}
  25% {background-color: orange;}
  50% {background-color: green;}
  75% {background-color: blue;}
  100% {background-color: red;}
}
```

You can change the `10s` to whatever duration (in seconds) you want the animation to play before repeating.